# A global mathematics library

Tags: soft-question

Just for personal interest, I am not (yet) professionally involved in it. My question is about the state of arts in digitalization of mathematics and to what extent it is possible and reasonable.

There are different levels of digitalizations:

1. OCR scan all historical mathematical texts
2. organize metadata of references and authors (e.g. as graphs)
3. extract mathematical objects (like theorems, definitions, etc)
4. extract proofs and ideas
5. formalize mathematics such that it can be completely checked by theorem provers

The main effort I found is
https://imkt.org/

Steps 3/4 and 5 may be of independent interest and should be understood more parallel than chronological. Point 5 is more interesting in having (error-free) formalized math. It should also be allowed to choose different foundations of mathematics and the possibility to switch in between them. Point 3/4 is more interesting for a researcher that wants all references for a definition, a theorem, a keyword. It would be a wonderful source for doing data analysis of mathematical knowledge (historical, social, semantical, etc). In contrast to 5 it can contain errors and speculations. The main interest is in identifying and referencing mathematical objects over all the produced texts in history of math.

My question is:

The goal of https://imkt.org/ is huge but when looking at its first projects it looks (sry) a little bit disappointing. The main focus (also of other literature that I scanned through) lies on connecting the existing databases and languages, i.e. of theorem provers, computer algebra systems (and maybe wikis). I understand that different applications in math demand different systems (e.g. integer series http://oeis.org/ should also be part of it?) Can or shouldn't there be one system that contains everything that can be accessed (and is stored not just referenced!) through the same system? Are my dreams of such a system over the top?

- One of the largest issues is the copyright of the big publishers.
  More and more is going in direction open math. Until then it is
  unclear to what extent a library can be complete (gaps are somehow
  missing the point of this system).
- The other issue is the efficiency in producing the content extraction
  and to advance it by advertising the advantages of such a library to
  mathematicians such that it will move itself at some point.

There have been many efforts in the past that were abandoned again or here for years (like [Mizar](http://mizar.org/)) but far from being known and used in daily mathematics.

Comment: You might look at the IMU and their efforts on WDML.  Part of the idea is to archive sites like MathOverflow which show the (relatively informalized) development of mathematics in this century.  Gerhard "Says 'Informalized' Is A Word" Paseman, 2020.07.15.

Comment: So far I just found articles either analyzing existing systems or abstractly sophisticating about properties that a perfect library should have. Do you know about a recent concrete effort of building a perfect system? And can you give me a link for that IMU effort? Sounds interesting.

Comment: IMU is international Mathematics Union. WDML is World Digital Mathematics Library.  I think you can find the links as well or better than I can.  Gerhard "Ingrid Posted About It Here" Paseman, 2020.07.15.

Comment: There is slow progress towards point 5 (see various libraries that have grown around systems like Coq and Mizar), but at the moment nothing too high can grow on this field since most proof languages are too unstable and don't feel like "the right thing" (so any work done now will probably have to be painstakingly adapted in 10 years if not earlier). Most of the time, these libraries are written by humans, typically inspired by existing literature but in no way just straightforwardly translating it. Maybe AI could do this in 20 years, but even that's far from a given.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand point 3 correctly: If I get it right, you would like to have a database which contains theorems, definitions, etc., and which links to articles books, etc, where they are used. I am, however, under the impression that this idea underestimates the diversity of mathematical literature, even within very specific sub-areas: For instance: What precisely is the statement of Banach's fixed point theorem? What is "the" Perron-Frobenius theorem in matrix analysis? What does the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs say? And these are only rather mild examples...

Comment: I am aware that there is sometimes no unique formulation of a theorem. That is not a problem. A perfect system/database would try to just capture exactly in a machine-readable form how a textbook states a theorem. Using some ML one then aggregates similar statements (the "same") theorems and displays them in a frontend view. Maybe listing the most stated version first and referring to other formulations etc.

Comment: First one needs a good strategy how to store statements. One this is defined the aggregating process and linking by ML and the user friendly search engine frontend can be independent and more and more improved over the years.

Comment: "Same theorem" is much more of a problem than you think.  Let me point out one particularly problematic situation.  The foundations of algebraic geometry were completely redone in the 1960s by Grothedieck and others, to the extent that modern algebraic geometers find it very hard to read the standard text of Hodge and Pedoe from the 1950s.  A much broader class of objects was introduced, and the objects previously studied were redefined in a different way.  (continued)

Comment: Some old theorems generalized to (at least some of) the new class of objects by doing the 'obvious' translation to the new language; some generalized but required genuinely new proofs; some remained true only for the 'classical' objects (redefined).  In which cases do we have the "same theorem"?

Answer (score 25):

None of your five levels of digitalization are at all within reach. Let's take just the first one. As you say, copyright is a huge obstacle. Consider what happened when the same idea was attempted by Google (resulting in Google Books), as explained wonderfully in [this article in the Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2017/04/the-tragedy-of-google-books/523320/). Larry Page (as in, PageRank) set up a tremendous effort to get books from libraries and scan them en masse with OCR technology to make them searchable.

After doing this for some time, publishers filed suit against Google. Google hired a massive legal team because it cared so much about creating such a library. Google managed to bring the publishers onboard with the idea, pointing out that it would allow publishers to sell out-of-print works. Unfortunately, this raised another issue, like a sad game of whack-a-mole, and the Department of Justice got involved to prevent Google from having a de-facto monopoly on out-of-print books. In the end, the Judge prevented the settlement that Google and the publishing companies had agreed to.

The same things would happen in the math world. The point is: you have a bunch of authors who died a long time ago and can't give consent to update their old publishing contracts. You have publishers who won't let go of content unless they can profit on it. And you don't have any organization large enough to be the central clearing house to connect customers who want to read these works with the places they can view and buy them. The problem only gets harder every year, because we produce more and more mathematics all the time (and OCR for math is not great, throwing a wrench into your third idea). My opinion: if Google couldn't pull together a global library, despite all the effort they put into this problem, there's no hope for the rest of us.

Comment: So end run around the old system:  publish newly created mathematics (and synopses and surveys of older math) under a free-to-distribute license.  Just because it was done the old-fashioned way does not mean it has to stay that way.  Gerhard "Get Rid Of Tradition,... Tradition!" Paseman, 2020.07.15.

Comment: Nice answer and also nice cited article. And I also partly agree with your conclusions: if the problem is dealt only on a pure economic interest basis, if Google has not succeeded, then no one will. However I hope that there will be more space for science and a little less (but reasonably sufficient) space for business. After all, the Taj-Mahal, St. Peter's Basilica, and almost everything it made by men that is worth to see, has not been built with the aim of making money about it.

Comment: De-facto, [Library Genesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_Genesis) is the library everyone uses these days as a first source for mathematics books; physical libraries are consulted as a last resort, for the rare books that are not (yet) on Library Genesis. But there is a huge gap between having a scan and having a readable "true PDF" or TeX file. [MathPix](https://mathpix.com/) is a promising OCR tool for mathematical formulas, but it has its limits, and typesetting can be **very** diverse. (Not to mention that lots of scans aren't good enough to leave OCR to machines.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg, I'm not sure that LibGen [is](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365718/a-global-mathematics-library#comment923431_365724) the preferred resource over library books for *everyone*.  A, uh, friend of mine definitely consults it whenever needed to stock an electronic library (say, for books to take along on travel), but, pre-pandemic, I would almost always go to the physical library to get a book (not an article).  It's just too hard to browse, properly to bookmark, to compare side-by-side, etc. in an electronic reference; the electronic reading experience remains sub-par for me.

Comment: @LSpice your friend can print out the relevant pages

Comment: @erz Many books cross-reference themselves across hundreds of pages constantly. There's a reason books are books, and not sequences of articles.

Comment: @KevinArlin one can print the whole book. Also, I think it is acceptable to print out only the relevant pages and read them from the paper, and once a reference to some early place pops out look it up on the screen

Comment: @LSpice: Having to crawl or climb on a chair to reach the appropriate shelves of a library isn't always fun either :) And I have to say, after seeing publisher after publisher lose the art of bookbinding, that there are many books I'd prefer to print out myself.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, I definitely have nothing against those who prefer e-books, and am glad that they're there when I need them (like in the US now—I'm definitely not going in our library, even when it opens).  I just don't agree that it's *everyone's* first choice.

Comment: What if there will be ONE country in the word which openly declare that they do not accept publisher rights, patents, etc., and by the law of this country everyone has the right to scan and put online any information they like? Then this country could create and maintain such database. If would be illegal in other countries, but at least it would exist.

Answer (score 11):

On my opinion, 2-5 are non-realistic (and hardly needed), while 1 is indeed desirable and important. To be sure, a substantial progress was made in the recent years towards 1. But it still remains a remote goal.

David White mentioned the main obstacle: the existing shameful copyright system. But there are several other obstacles. The number of math periodicals is really enormous, many were owned by universities and various societies in the past, and there is no real will to digitalize all these obscure publications. There are many old publications of various societies in most European countries which are still not digitalized. Big companies probably see no perspective of profit in this (and they are probably right), and volunteers have more important things to do.

As I understand copyright does not apply to 18-19 centuries math journals.
Still, there is little interest in their digitalization. Few big journals
which still continue, digitalized the old issues (and claim copyright for this digitalization). But no one seems to be interested in those journals which do not continue.

In many cases, even when a digitalization is available, the quality is too poor to read or print, or search. The old volumes of Comptes rendus are available, but try to find anything in them. Sometimes they show you "digitalized" pages on the screen but do not allow to download the pdf file of the article. So you are supposed to print a large paper one page at a time, if allowed to print at all.

The result is easy to predict: with the current demise of the usual libraries, most this mathematics will be simply lost. And no realistic remedy is visible. Well, this is not the first time that such thing happens: by various estimates about 90% of Hellenistic mathematics and science were lost. (And practically 100% of Greek pre-Hellenistic).

Of course one can argue that "the most important" works are preserved. For example Euclid is preserved but all his predecessors are not. Perhaps there is some truth in this. (Imagine that of all 20 century mathematics only Bourbaki is preserved:-)

Comment: I”m not sure I agree on your 18-19 centuries assessment. Most everything to 1850 or 1900 is scanned and [available](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7680) in archives like numdam, gallica, hathitrust, biodiversity, archive.org that seem safe even if Google books were to shut down. After 1950 or so is another matter with, anyway, a much reduced [signal/noise](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7720).

Comment: Most German "provincial" journals (which have names beginning with Sitzungsberichte, Abhandlungen, etc. are not digitalized, even the famous one published in Gottingen). And this is only one example. The famous Russian journal Doklady of the Academy is not digitalized. We only have translations for few years when it was translated.

Comment: Well, the link leads to a list where everything from Göttingen seems available (GDZ). Likewise Leipzig ([babel](//catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/003854381), [wikisource](//de.wikisource.org/wiki/Sächsische_Akademie_der_Wissenschaften)).

Comment: The links you provided even do not contain the word "Göttingen".

Comment: My first comment, linked word “available”. Search the list there for “Göttingen”. One of the links seems broken but here it is again, [fixed](//de.wikisource.org/wiki/Abhandlungen_der_Königlichen_Gesellschaft_der_Wissenschaften_zu_Göttingen).

Comment: Here is the complete title of the journal I was never able to find:  Nachrichten von der Königlichen Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften und der Georg-Augusts-Universität zu Göttingen (and still cannot).

Comment: [(1)](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN668664029), [(2)](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Nachrichten_von_der_Königlichen_Gesellschaft_der_Wissenschaften_zu_Göttingen), [(3)](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Nachrichten_von_der_Gesellschaft_der_Wissenschaften_zu_Göttingen_–_Mathematisch-Physikalische_Klasse), [(4)](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/009686580),...

Comment: You say Doklady is not digitized. It is available for the period 1957-1995 at http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?jrnid=dan&wshow=contents&viewarchiveID=8&option_lang=eng

Comment: Why isn't there an effort to survey this old mathematics to prevent it from vanishing? I don't think the texts as such are all that valuable, it's the ideas that are there.

Comment: @erz: I can give you one reason: reading old mathematics is difficult and requires highest qualification. People who have it prefer to spend their time more productively: by proving their own theorems:-)

Comment: @KConrad: this appeared recently, thanks for noticing. Still the first 111 volumes are not available. Hope they will do all volumes it eventually.

Comment: Earlier volumes of Doklady back to 1933 are listed online at https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000053018 but the volumes can only be searched by keyword.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of work lately on formalizing large parts of classical mathematics using proof assistants, see for example the [Lean prover](https://leanprover.github.io/) and the accompanying library [mathlib](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib). You can see an overview of what has been formalized [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib-overview.html); it includes a lot of classical abstract algebra and real analysis, although there's also a lot of undergraduate math they haven't formalized yet which they list [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/undergrad_todo.html). If you think that's all "trivial", there's ongoing work to formalize the proof of the independence of the [continuum hypothesis](https://flypitch.github.io/), the proof that it's possible to [evert the sphere](https://leanprover-community.github.io/sphere-eversion/), etc.

An interesting facet of this project is that all the proofs are kept under a version control system and you can see the entire history of every proof. It's common for the initial proof of some result to be very long and verbose, only for people to find ways to shorten it or make it more elegant later -- for example, von Neumann's proof of the Radon-Nikodym theorem. Where before you might have had to trace through the citations of loads of historical papers that your library might not even have, now you can see exactly how this process played out by just doing `git blame`.